# gcloud AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'aes_key_wrap_with_padding'

Tags: import, key, gcloud

I am trying to import plaintext key generated by openssl using glcloud but getting below error
(AttributeError): 'module' object has no attribute 'aes_key_wrap_with_padding'

while executing command
gcloud kms keys versions import --import-job importjb1--location global --keyring test --key key123 --algorithm google-symmetric-encryption --target-key-file C:\abcd\PlainTextKey.bin

Prior to executing above command, I did pip install --user "cryptography>=2.2.0" and have set env variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES to 1

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times this error comes down to whether it was installed the version of Cryptography module that's appropriate for the Python environment.
You can use the [debug flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) of gcloud to get additional information along with the "[gcloud info --anonymize](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/info#--anonymize)" (watch for accidentally sharing sensitive data from these commands)